# Running Unity UWP applications, with Vuforia, on Windows 10

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, uwp, runtime, vuforia

I need to run an Unity project with Vuforia, compiled as UWP application on a Windows 10 PC.

I'm trying UWP format because Vuforia don't support classic windows build.

Inside Unity Editor everything works perfectly in game mode but compiling it as UWP Exe some dlls are missing:

- vccorlib140_app.dll
- vcruntime140_app.dll
- vcruntime140_1_app.dll

I tried to download runtime package here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/cpp/c-runtime-packages-desktop-bridge

But all installers don't work, and return this error:

> App installation failed with error message: error 0x80073D02: Unable
> to install because the following apps need to be closed
> Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_1.4.3161.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.
> (0x80073d02)